# Read phar file from memory?

Tags: php, phar

Is there a way that I can access a file from a phar without having to save the phar to disk first?  In the following code, `$fileContentsString` is the contents of a phar file that was loaded from the network.  How can I take that string and read a file from it without having to save the string to disk as a file first?  I've tried writing the string to `php://temp` and then using `Phar::loadPhar` to read it, but that fails.

```php
$tmpFilePath = TMP_PATH . '/' . $filename;

// Save the file to TMP_PATH
$fp = fopen($tmpFilePath, 'w');
fwrite($fp, $fileContentsString);
fclose($fp);

$contents = file_get_contents('phar://' . $tmpFilePath . '/json.txt');
```

Answer (score 1):

`php://temp` is a stream that can be used to store data in memory - but it can be only used via a file handle, not as a file system.
Opening another file handle on `php://temp` will give you another part of the memory, and thus a new "file".

You need a memory-only file system like PEAR's [Stream_Var package](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.streams.stream-var.example.php) which lets you access variables as a file system.